# Remote Event Receiver is not being triggered

Tags: remote-event-receiver

I have a list called clients, when a new item is added to the list a new sub site should be created.
I created an Azure Service Bus and copy pasted the ACS connection string for debugging.

I can debug the App Installed event without any problems, however when a new item is added to the list breakpoints are never hit.

I checked on Sharepoint Client Browser and the remote event receiver is there.
http://screencast.com/t/OoPDhqRq

The code to add the RER and to execute the item added is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers;
using Capatech.IntranetWeb.Provisioning;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace xx.IntranetWeb.Services
{
    public class AppEventReceiver : IRemoteEventService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles app events that occur after the app is installed or upgraded, or when app is being uninstalled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties">Holds information about the app event.</param>
        /// <returns>Holds information returned from the app event.</returns>
        public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
            try
            {              
                switch (properties.EventType)
                {
                    case SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled:
                        AppEvents.AppInstalled(properties);
                        result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
                        break;
                    case SPRemoteEventType.AppUninstalling:
                        //this.HandleAppUnInstall(properties);
                        result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
                        break;
                    case SPRemoteEventType.AppUpgraded:
                        AppEvents.AppUpgraded(properties);
                        result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
                        break;

                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log message
                result.ErrorMessage = "Capatech.Intranet:  " + ex.Message;
                result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
                return result;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To handle list events
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties"></param>
        public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            //Remote event receivers for clients
            if (properties.ListEventProperties.ListTitle == "Clientes")
            {
                switch (properties.EventType)
                {
                    case SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded:
                        Clients.HandleItemClientAdded(properties);
                        break;
                    case SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdated:
                        Clients.HandleItemClientAdded(properties);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }




    }
}



    {
        const string CLIENTES_ITEMADDED = "CLIENTES_ITEMADDED";
        const string CLIENTES_ITEMUPDATED = "CLIENTES_ITEMUPDATED";

        /// <summary>
        /// Associate RER to client list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientcontext">Client context</param>
        public static void AssociateItemAddedEventReceiverToClientList(ClientContext clientcontext)
        {
            List clientList = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Clientes");
            clientcontext.Load(clientList);

            var eventReceivers = clientList.EventReceivers;
            clientcontext.Load(eventReceivers);

            clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

            var rerExists = false;

            foreach (var rer in clientList.EventReceivers)
            {
                if (rer.ReceiverName == CLIENTES_ITEMADDED)
                {
                    rerExists = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Found existing ItemAdded receiver at " + rer.ReceiverUrl);
                }
            }

            if (!rerExists)
            {
                EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
                receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
                //receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
                //Get WCF URL where this message was handled
                OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
                Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;

                receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();
                receiver.ReceiverName = CLIENTES_ITEMADDED;
                //Add the new event receiver to a list in the host web

                clientList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);

                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is executed when a new client is added to the list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties">Remote vent properties</param>
        public static void HandleItemClientAdded(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {           
            using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    CreateClientSiteAndUpdateSiteOnList(properties, clientContext);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to create a client site
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties">Remote event properties</param>
        /// <param name="clientContext">Client Context</param>
        private static void CreateClientSiteAndUpdateSiteOnList(SPRemoteEventProperties properties, ClientContext clientContext)
        {
            List requestList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);
            ListItem item = requestList.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
            clientContext.Load(item);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            string site_title = item["NIT"].ToString() + " " + item["Nombre Cliente"].ToString();
            string site_url = item["NIT"].ToString();

            Web newWeb = clientContext.Web.CreateWeb(site_title, site_url, site_title, "STS#0", 1033);
            clientContext.Load(newWeb);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //Updates site on the client list
            FieldUrlValue siteUrl = new FieldUrlValue();
            siteUrl.Url = newWeb.Url;
            siteUrl.Description = site_title + " Sitio";
            item["Sitio Cliente"] = siteUrl;
            item.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure properties on the client fields
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ctx">Client context</param>
        public static void ConfigureClientFields(ClientContext ctx)
        {
            List clientList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Clientes");
            ctx.Load(clientList);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            clientList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Sitio Cliente").SetShowInNewForm(false);
            clientList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Version Sitio").SetShowInEditForm(false);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is executed when a client info is updated
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties">Remote event properties</param>
        public static void HandleItemClientUpdated(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the `ItemAdded` code from `ProcessOneWayEvent` to `ProcessEvent` and that's it.